# TypeScript DefinitelyTyped Ember.js d.ts doesn't compile

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ember.js, typescript

I am trying to get definitions for the Ember.js library to work with TypeScript. Whenever I try to reference the ember-1.0.d.ts file I get 43 instances of the error:

```
The name 'Ember' does not exist in the current scope.
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with TypeScript and the Web Essentials package installed, thinking maybe it was a problem with my own configuration I tried to load a different .d.ts from the DefinitelyType project. I tried to reference the Angular.js definition file and it gives me no errors so I am assuming there is something wrong with the definition file.

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/Definitions/ember-1.0.d.ts

What could be the cause of this error?

This is one of the parts that gives me errors, the Ember.* parts are marked as wrong:

```
export interface Enumerable extends Mixin {
    // Fields
    firstObject: Object;
    hasEnumerableObservers: bool;
    lastObject: Object;
    nextObject: Object;

    // Methods
    addEnumerableObserver(target, opts);
    compact(): any[];
    contains(obj: Object): bool;
    enumerableContentDidChange(removing: number, adding: number): Object;
    enumerableContentDidChange(removing: Ember.Enumerable, adding: Ember.Enumerable): Object;
    enumerableContentDidChange(start: Number, removing: number, adding: number): Object;
    enumerableContentDidChange(start: Number, removing: Ember.Enumerable, adding: Ember.Enumerable): Object;

    enumerableContentWillChange(removing: number, adding: number): Ember.Enumerable;
    enumerableContentWillChange(removing: Ember.Enumerable, adding: Ember.Enumerable): Ember.Enumerable;
    enumerableContentWillChange(start: Number, removing: number, adding: number): Ember.Enumerable;
    enumerableContentWillChange(start: Number, removing: Ember.Enumerable, adding: Ember.Enumerable): Ember.Enumerable;

    every(callback: Function, target?: Object): bool;
    everyProperty(key: string, value?: string): any[];
    filter(callback: Function, target?: Object): any[];
    filterProperty(key: string, value?: string): any[];
    find(callback: Function, target?: Object): Object;
    findProperty(key: string, value?: string): Object;
    /*forEach
    getEach
    invoke
    map
    mapProperty
    reduce
    removeEnumerableObserver
    setEach
    some
    someProperty
    toArray
    uniq
    without*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made two changes in Visual Studio to get this working.

In the declaration I changed:

```
declare module "Ember" {
```

To

```
declare module Ember {
```

And in your interface I changed:

```
interface Enumerable extends Mixin {
```

To

```
interface Enumerable extends Ember.Mixin {
```

After this all the warnings were gone.

Comment: Thank you. It appears that all the errors disappear after the quotation marks are removed. Even without having to add Ember.Mixin to the interface Enumerable extends. Is there any reason to add that too?

Comment: There are a few objects in the `Ember` module that may have name-clashes, for example `Ember.Object` might be mistaken for the global `Object`.