# How to use TypeScript with Ember.js

Tags: typescript, ember.js

I have an existing project in ember. I have used JavaScript so far in the project. However, I want to use TypeScript in the same project but leave the existing code as is. Whatever I write now on I want to do it in TS.
What would be the best practice and more importantly do I have to setup the project to facilitate it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this add-on: https://github.com/emberwatch/ember-cli-typescript#incremental-adoption. There is a note there about https://github.com/emberwatch/ember-cli-typescript#incremental-adoption. Since TypeScript is just JavaScript + Type you can just rename the files to ts and it will work. I have not tried this on existing project.

Comment: I do not want to change existing parts of my project. I want it to be JS only. However, whatever comes next, I would like to try TS on it. Do I need the addon anyway? Can't I just start adding TS files to project, as Ember supports TS inherently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript DefinitelyTyped Ember.js d.ts doesn't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251294/typescript-definitelytyped-ember-js-d-ts-doesnt-compile)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can keep your existing `js` files intact and start adding new `ts` files to your existing project with:

```
yarn add typescript -D
ember install ember-cli-typescript@latest
```

After that your app should keep working as usual. Now you can change the extension of individual files from `js` to `ts` if you want Typescript to process them. Or, simple add new files with the `ts` extension.

The addon will also create `ts` files for new objects, ex:

```
ember g helper foobar
installing helper
  create app/helpers/foobar.ts
installing helper-test
  create tests/integration/helpers/foobar-test.ts
```